# How to accurately throttle FPS in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, frame-rate

I am working on an application that continuously polls windows for graphics drawn in video and games, takes a screen capture, and then does some processing. I am trying to implement a configurable FPS throttle to avoid using resources unnecessarily when it doesn't need to be running at such a high frame rate.

I've created this loop class and use a Stopwatch with elapsed ticks to calculate how long each frame takes to process and to throttle the current frame if it's processing too fast for the desired FPS.

Running this results in the FPS sitting around 35-40 when the target FPS is 60, and changing the target FPS results in an actual FPS in the same ratio as 35-40 / 60 actual to target. I've double checked the math and can't seem to figure out what's going wrong, as debugging it is tricky because breakpoints affect the elapsed time. Any suggestions on how to fix my loop or what's going wrong?

```
    public class ProcessLoop
    {
        const int TARGET_FPS = 60;
        const long OPTIMAL_TIME = (TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / TARGET_FPS);

        private static Stopwatch _time = new Stopwatch();
        private int _frames = 0;
        private int _fps = 0;

        public void Run(CancellationToken stoppingToken, Action process)
        {
            _time.Start();
            long lastLoopTime = _time.ElapsedTicks;
            long lastSecondUpdate = lastLoopTime;

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                lastLoopTime = _time.ElapsedTicks;

                // Process one frame here
                process();
                _frames++;

                // The time after processing work
                var now = _time.ElapsedTicks;

                // How long it took to process the work done this frame
                var deltatime = now - lastLoopTime;

                if (now - lastSecondUpdate >= TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
                {
                    _fps = _frames;
                    _frames = 0;
                    lastSecondUpdate = 0;
                    _time.Restart();
                    Console.WriteLine($"FPS: {_fps}");
                }

                // Sleep to approach optimal time per frame
                if (deltatime < OPTIMAL_TIME)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromTicks(OPTIMAL_TIME - deltatime));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Thread.Sleep`

There's your problem, relinquishing a thread in a protected OS like Windows offers no guaratee that you'll get it back in the time specified. In fact, you are guaranteed to not get it back in the time you request, ever. It even says so in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-7.0).

Either busy wait until the right time (high CPU usage), or use a hybrid approach (if it's essential to use as little CPU as possible) where you do tiny sleeps until you get "close enough" to the target time (~3ms with high precision timing enabled) then busy wait the rest of the way there.

Comment: Thanks! It's much more accurate now that I implemented your suggestion of busy waiting with something like: `var nextUpdateTime = now + (OPTIMAL_TIME - deltatime);`
I will look into the hybrid approach as well if needed.

Comment: Typically games will always busy wait, since perfectly spaced frames are extremely important and they already use a fair amount of CPU anyway. More business-oriented applications, especially ones that are expected to run multiple instances on the same machine, go with the hybrid approach. For example, I had to write the hybrid approach into a system that simulates aircraft CDUs (display units) in a commercial sim because there's dozens of these things running on the same CPU and it was running out of cores to busy wait.